# MySQL: Search on Fulltext index using MATCH and INSTR

Tags: mysql

In a FULLTEXT indexed field containing word `ddi`. Now I'm searching that word using MATCH() function as below, but it is returning 0 record:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_xxx`
WHERE MATCH(`full_content`) AGAINST ('ddi' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
-- RETURNING 0 RECORDS :(
```

But when I'm searching using INSTR() function then it returns 1 record

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_xxx`
WHERE INSTR(`full_content`, 'ddi')
-- RETURNS 1 RECORD :)
```

**Why using INSTR() returning 1 record but not with MATCH().**

The table `tbl_xxx` has Engine type = MyISAM and field `full_content` is indexed using FULLTEXT

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum word length to the full-text search feature in MySQL. Chances are yours is set to a value greater than three. You can configure it in your my.cnf file like so:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

For more information, check out the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Comment: Added `ft_min_word_len=3` to my.cnf and restarted MySQL but still getting 0 record for FULLTEXT search!

Comment: If you run "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_%'", what are the results?

Comment: Yes seen this:
`ft_boolean_syntax + -><()~*:""&|` 
`ft_max_word_len 84` 
`ft_min_word_len 3` 
`ft_query_expansion_limit 20` 
`ft_stopword_file (built-in)`